# Reverse proxy nginx docker container with subdomains

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker-compose.yml file with multiple services connected to the same network. the services include nginx exposes port 80, a web app(app1) running on 0.0.0.0:8000, a second web app(app2) running on 0.0.0.0:7000, yet another web app(app3) running on 0.0.0.0:5000 and so on

I can access all the apps from the browser when a go to 0.0.0.0:8000 or 0.0.0.0:5000 etc

I want to access the first app with "http://localhost" from the browser  i.e the first web app to be the root. then the others to be subdomains for example; for app2 to be access from this: "http://localhost/app2"

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have created a server block for each web app as shown bellow

```
 >> cat app1.conf
upstream app1 {
        server app1:8000;
}
server {
        # this server listens on port 80
        listen 80 ;
        
        server_name app1;

        # the location / means that when we visit the root url (localhost:80/), we use this configuration
        location / {
                
           proxy_pass http://app1;
        }
       
        
}
```

now for one of the subdomains i have :

```
upstream app2 {
        server app2:8000;
}
server {
        # this server listens on port 80
        listen 80 ;
        
        server_name app2;

        # the location / means that when we visit the root url (localhost:80/), we use this configuration
        location /app2 {
                
           proxy_pass http://app2;
        }      
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"
 services:
  app1:
    image: app1 image
    container_name: app1
    networks:
      - local-network
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  app2:
    image: app2 image
    container_name: app2
    networks:
      - local-network
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
   
  app3:
    image: app3 image
    container_name: app3
    networks:
      - local-network
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
   
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - local-network
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/sites-available/app1.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-available/app1.conf
        - ./nginx/sites-available/app2.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-available/app2.conf
        - ./nginx/sites-available/app3.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-available/app3.conf
        - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
      - app3
 networks:
   local-network
```

in my nginx.conf I including the sites-enabled and manually created symlink of the mounted sites-available configuration files in the nginx container.

On the browser "http://localhost/" works fine but "http://localhost/app1" or `app2` or `app3` redirects to http://localhost/
There are no errors in the docker logs

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: that's just port redirection with nginx, if you really meant subdomains you would acces containers with app1.domain.com or app2.domain.com etc (eg api.domain, blog.domain...) Can anyone tell me how to implement subdomains with nginx, i dont want to use jwilder ty

Comment: Have you solved? I'm with the same doubt, I don't want to use twilder either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example, both nginx conf file and docker-compose.yml below:

```
~/Projects/docker/echo-test $ tree

.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── nginx
    └── app.conf

1 directory, 2 files
```

```
~/Projects/docker/echo-test $ cat nginx/app.conf

upstream app1 {
        server echoer1:7777;
}
upstream app2 {
        server echoer2:8888;
}
upstream app3 {
        server echoer3:9999;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://app1;
        }
        location /app2 {
                proxy_pass http://app2;
        }
        location /app3 {
                proxy_pass http://app3;
        }
}
```

```
~/Projects/docker/echo-test $ cat docker-compose.yml

version: "3.8"
services:
  echoer1:
    hostname: echoer1
    image: mendhak/http-https-echo
    environment:
      - HTTP_PORT=7777

  echoer2:
    hostname: echoer2
    image: mendhak/http-https-echo
    environment:
      - HTTP_PORT=8888

  echoer3:
    hostname: echoer3
    image: mendhak/http-https-echo
    environment:
      - HTTP_PORT=9999

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: I tried your way and now am getting error 404 Not Found even on the root url (http://localhost)

Comment: I think nginx app.conf has wrong port mapping it should be 7070, 8080 and 9090 respectively. Please try this.

Comment: @RuthMbugua want to upload your example to github, so I can take a look?

Comment: @AlokSingh no, it shouldn't be. Externally published ports has nothing to do with inter-container communications, the only reason I published ports 7070, 8080 and 9090 was to test the echo containers and see how the response looks like. I will update the post to not have ports published at all and it will still work.

Comment: @RuthMbugua try accessing by 127.0.0.1 instead of the localhost. Alternatively add the `localhost` to the server_name instruction in the app.conf, I will update the post to have that.

Comment: @RuthMbugua, here is [mine](https://github.com/jabbson/q69891985) if that makes it any easier

Comment: @jabbson let me try with the environment if it doesn't work  will share the github link